# How to disable the filesystem cache on the root device?

Tags: linux, qemu

I've got an ARM virtual machine running on top of KVM/QEMU, with a file mounted as the root filesystem. The VM doesn't have networking, so NFS mounting the root is out of the question. I am testing a particular transport mechanism for IO, so I'm kind of stuck with what I've got.

I want to send files into the guest, so I'd like to mount the file on the host, write things to it, and then unmount it to force a flush. The contents of the filesystem are trivial, and I have a backup, so I have no problem with corruption. Likewise, performance is not an issue.

The problem is, when I do this mount-write-unmount thing, the guest never sees the file. I'm guessing this is a result of the kernel's filesystem cache, and that when I do ls, the file isn't there. I'm guessing the metadata concerning the filesystem are cached in memory, and the updates to the filesystem never appear.

I'm guessing if I disable filesystem caching, then all reads will be forced to disk, causing the filesystem to be hit, and my file to appear. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of this:

```
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And this:

```
qemu -drive cache=none,file=file.img
```